# Deleting a Resource

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crud

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. I need to delete a record. In my controller, I have an action that looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Orders() 
{
  return View();
}

[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult Orders(int orderId)
{
  return RedirectToAction("Orders", new { d = "true" });
}
```

In my view, I have:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onclick="return deleteOrder(@order.OrderId);">Delete Order</button>

function deleteOrder(id) {
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/OrderController/Orders/',
      type: 'DELETE',
      data: {
        orderId: id
      }
    });
  }
  return false;
}
```

Oddly, with this approach the `[HttpDelete] Orders` is never reached. I'm not sure how to get a delete action to work in the MVC action.

Comment: What is the response status code that you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your `url` is wrong. You do not need to specify the sufix `Controller` on your class and the best way to get the right url according the route tables is using the `Url` property in the `View`.

Anoth point is your async request (delete action method) returns a redirect and you should deal with it on the client-side because the jquery will not redirect the client. You could try this:

on client-side

```
 $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("Orders", "Order")',
      type: 'DELETE',
      data: {
        orderId: id
      },
      success: function(data) {
          if (data.success) {
             window.location.href = data.redirectUrl;
          }
      }
 });
```

on the server-side:

```
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult Orders([FromBody]int orderId)
{
   // check if it is an async request
  if (Request.IsAjaxRequest)
  {
     return Json(new { success = true, urlRedirect = Url.Action("Orders", new { d = "true "});
  }

  return RedirectToAction("Orders", new { d = "true" });
}
```

Comment: when I update the route, I get to the action. However, the redirect does not work. It constantly redirects back to itself. Its like it doesn't go to the "GET" action.

Comment: Try using the `[FromBody]` on the action method. If it does not work, you have to pass the id from the url.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Change:

```
url: '/OrderController/Orders/',
```

To

```
url: '/Order/Orders/',
```

`Controller` is an ASP.NET MVC convention and it's not included in the url.

Comment: when I update the route, I get to the action. However, the redirect does not work. It constantly redirects back to itself. Its like it doesn't go to the "GET" action.

Comment: You can't do an HTTP redirect through an AJAX request. But that is another question altogether.